# PowerShell How to loop a script based on script array count

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

I'm new to PowerShell. I'm trying to pull a users name and place it in a file. I have two corresponding arrays, $title and $csvfile. $title[0] corresponds with $csvfile[0] and $title[1] to $csvfile[1] and so on. Is it possible to loop this script while increasing the index for both at the same time so that each index runs once but also in sync?

```
$title = @('jim' 'john' 'james')
$csvfile = @('jim.csv' 'john.csv' 'james.csv')

Get -ADUser -filter {(Title -like "$title") -and (Company -like "Location1")} | Export-Csv c:\temp\$csvfile
```

Problem 2
The $title array doesn't seem to be iterating one at a time.  If I replace $title[$] with any of the listed array items it works.  Funny thing is that it DOES create all my .csv files from the $csvfile array, they are just empty.  I've done some looking on the web, not sure if my array items are to long or the quotations are not parsing right.  Any help would be muchly appreciated.

```
    $title = @(
   'Director of Nursing'
   'Assistant Director of Nursing'
   'Activities Director'
)
   $csvfile = @(
  'DON'
  'ADON'
  'ACTIVITIES'
)

    for($i=0; $i -lt $title.Count; $i++)
{
    #Get-ADUser -Filter { (Title -like "Director of Nursing")  -and  (Company -like "location1") }| Export-Csv c:\temp\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"
    Get-ADUser -filter { (Title -like "$($title[$i])")  -and  (Company -like "Location1") }| Export-Csv "c:\tempPath\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly. You'd like to append the user information from `Get-Aduser` to the corresponding csv of the users name you got it from? Such as, `jim` info goes to `jim.csv`, and so on for each one?

Seems like you're looking for the `Foreach` loop.

```
$title = @('jim','john','james')
#$csvfile = @('jim.csv' 'john.csv' 'james.csv')

Foreach($user in $title){
Get-ADUser -filter {(Title -like "$title") -and (Company -like "Location1")} | Export-Csv "c:\temp\$title.csv"}
```

A `Foreach` loop goes through a list of objects and performs the same action for every object, ending when it's finished with the last one. The list  of objects is typically an array. When you run a loop over a list of objects, we say you're `iterating` over the list.

The `Foreach` loop can be used in 3 different ways: `Foreach` Statement, `Foreach-Object` cmdlet, or as a `foreach()` method.

What we're using here is the `Foreach` statement which is followed by parentheses that contain three elements, in order: a variable, the keyword `in`, and the object or array to iterate over. As it moves through list (`$title`-array in this case), Powershell will copy the object it's looking at into the Variable defining each item in the list, `$user`.

> Note: because the variables is just a copy, you cannot directly change the item in the original list.

Please note as well, the items in an array are read separately by adding a comma to the end of each item in the list(if its not in a new line). In the code above, we're appending the same name you're iterating with to the csv file as well.

EDIT: Using `for` loop. . .

```
$title = @('jim','john','james')
$csvfile = @('CEO','CFO','CIO')


For($i=0; $i -lt $title.Count; $i++){
Get-ADUser -filter {(Title -like "$($title[$i])") -and (Company -like "Location1")} | Export-Csv "c:\temp\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"}
```

Matches the output like so:

```
jim - CEO.csv
john - CFO.csv
james - CIO.csv
```

Comment: Id like to ask if i may, why are you appending all the information to a new CSV for each user? Is there specific information you'd like to gather from the user?

Comment: Thanks Abraham, yes, I'm attempting to extract the email address from the user and place it in a unique csv file.  

For the second array, the $csvfile, could I pre create existing indexes associated with the user, equal indexes in both arrays?  So instead of "jim" transferring over to "jim.csv" how could I create his position of CEO.csv and have his info automatically  index at [0] and say the next user, "john" index at [1] at CFO.csv?

Comment: @GoodFox, what you're looking for is a `for` loop. See edit.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear, if you'd like some more information on how the `for` loop works, Iet me know and iIl edit the post again with info on it for future reference.

Comment: I've added a second problem section up top in my original post. Hopefully you can help.  The $title array doesn't seem to be iterating while the $csvfile does. I can enter the $title items manually and pull results but when looped i get nothing.

Comment: @GoodFox, hmm, that's odd. Can you add a foreach at the top like so: `Foreach($user in $title){
    for($i=0; $i -lt $title.Count; $i++){
    #Get-ADUser -Filter { (Title -like "Director of Nursing")  -and  (Company -like "location1") }| Export-Csv c:\temp\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"
    Get-ADUser -filter { (Title -like $user)  -and  (Company -like "Location1") }| Export-Csv "c:\tempPath\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"}
}`

Comment: for testing purposes, can you remove everything out and just run: `" $($title[$i]) - $($csvfile[$i])"`

Comment: No luck, the foreach does run and I still get all the .csv files created but they are still empty.  I ran the " $($title[$i]) - $($csvfile[$i])" and it returned a "0".  It doesn't make sense, the logic behind the code seems right.

Comment: In the first setup, does it make a difference if you remove the double quotes leaving `$(title[$i])`

Comment: I'd recommend asking again with problem #2 on this site. I'm sure someone much smarter than me can answer it. I'm kinda lost on why it's not being picked up; I wonder if we have to expand the whole filter, or or try something else.

Comment: So this was the issue.

Comment: That's add cause I tried the same exact same thing and it didn't work for me. Hmm, guess in theory it makes sense. Thank you for the update!!!